# Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, console

I got the message that says:

`"Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."` in WordPress console.

Is this affect the website performance or anything else?
If so, how can we resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled all installed extensions in Chrome - works for me. I have now clear console without errors.